# Are there any example on how to write full-screen apps for Mac OS X in Objective-C with Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, fullscreen

Could someone point me to any examples on how to write full-screen apps for Mac OS X in Ojective-C with Cocoa?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the following code to the NSView you want to make fullscreen:

`[view enterFullScreenMode:[NSScreen mainScreen] withOptions:nil];`

It's exactly the same, the only thing you need to watch for is if you have any NSWindow specific code...

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html

Comment: This is only available in 10.5 and later, but it is extremely easy to do. If you want to support 10.5, the view has to be in a window, but it does not have to be if you only want 10.6.

Comment: @hauntsaninja, but how to escape the full screen mode? My View used the same code above, and was not responded to the "esc" keyboard event.

Answer (score 2):

http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=02

There is an OSX Cocoa example for many of the tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (void)toggleMyViewFullScreen:(id)sender
{
    if (myView.inFullScreenMode) {
      [myView exitFullScreenModeWithOptions:nil];
    } else {
      NSApplicationPresentationOptions options =
          NSApplicationPresentationHideDock |       
          NSApplicationPresentationHideMenuBar;

      [myView enterFullScreenMode:[NSScreen mainScreen] withOptions:@{
             NSFullScreenModeApplicationPresentationOptions : @(options) }];
                                                                                 }];
    }
}
```

You can connect this to the fullscreen menu item in the Window menu (after inserting that into your nib) but be sure to change the action that the menu item fires to your toggleMyViewFullScreen: .  Or your can invoke toggleMyViewFullScreen programmatically or when your app loads.